# Handle multiple-rows through join mysql tables via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the id of an album and I'd like to show all the tracks of this album in a json file.
An album has many tracks and a track has many producers (artists).

**Database Structure**

[image: database structure]

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tracks 
         LEFT JOIN produced ON produced.produced_track = tracks.track_id 
         LEFT JOIN artists ON produced.produced_artist = artists.artist_id 
WHERE tracks.track_album = 1
```

**Result**

[image: MySQL Result]

**What I'd like to show via PHP**

[image: PHP result]

I'd like to create a json object with the different tracks and their related artists. My problem is how I could handle the sql result in order to create this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `SQL` code as per your final output I use.

```
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
  `track_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `track_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `produced_track` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `produced_artist` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `artist_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `tracks`(`track_id`,`track_name`,`produced_track`,`produced_artist`,`artist_id`,`artist_name`) values (1,'Get Luckey Original  ',1,3,3,'Daft Prunk'),(1,'Get Luckey Original  ',1,4,4,'Pharell'),(2,'Touch',1,5,3,'Daft Prunk'),(2,'Touch',1,5,5,'Paul');
```

And this is `PHP` code.

```
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT track_id,track_name,GROUP_CONCAT(artist_id) AS artist_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(artist_name SEPARATOR 0x1D ) AS artist_name FROM tracks GROUP BY track_id");
$i = 0;
while($v = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
        $arr [$i]['track_id'] = $v['track_id'];
        $arr [$i]['name'] = $v['track_name'];
        $artist_name_array = explode( chr(29) , $v['artist_name'] );
        foreach($artist_id_array = explode(',',$v['artist_id']) as $k1 => $v1 ){
            $arr [$i]['artists'][] = array ( 'id' => $artist_id_array[$k1] , 'name' => $artist_name_array[$k1] ) ;
        }
        $i++;

}
echo json_encode($arr);exit;
```

Here us your final output.

```
[
    {
        "track_id": "1",
        "name": "Get Luckey Original  ",
        "artists": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Daft Prunk"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Pharell"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "track_id": "2",
        "name": "Touch",
        "artists": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Daft Prunk"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Paul"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As per your `JOIN` query use this

```
SELECT track_id,track_name,GROUP_CONCAT(artist_id) AS artist_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(artist_name SEPARATOR 0x1D ) AS artist_name FROM tracks 
         LEFT JOIN produced ON produced.produced_track = tracks.track_id 
         LEFT JOIN artists ON produced.produced_artist = artists.artist_id
```